# Are collagen supplements of any use to help prevent or treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: micronutrients, tendinopathy, collagen

Are [collagen supplements](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/hpc/3774321/?sa-no-redirect=1) been scientifically shown of any use to help prevent or treat a tendinopathy? If so, what kind of collagen supplements (e.g., type of collagen, source of collagen [such as](http://amino-collagen.com/collagen-supplements-comparison.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181107235521/https://amino-collagen.com/collagen-supplements-comparison.html)) piscine, bovine, porcine, or fowl)?

I read from {1}:

> glucosamine and chondroitin sulphate, vitamin C, hydrolazed type 1 collagen, arginine alpha-keto-glutarate, bromelain, curcumin, boswellic acid, and methil-sulfonil-methane were considered […]. preclinical results are very encouraging, however they are not fully confirmed by clinical studies. There are few clinical papers on the use of nutraceuticals in tendon disorders, and their methodological quality is poor. Furthermore, in most of the studies more than one supplement was administered at the same time. This may bias the results, and the effect of each single component cannot be determined. Furthermore, the interactions between nutraceuticals and drugs, or other dietary supplements (especially at high doses) has not been evaluated, neither their effects on chronic diseases. For these reasons, it is not possible to draw any definitive raccomendations on the use of nutraceutical supplementation in tendinopathies.

I wonder whether more conclusive studies have been published since then.

---

References:

- {1} Federico Fusini, Salvatore Bisicchia, Carlo Bottegoni, Antonio Gigante,3 Fabio Zanchini, and Alberto Busilacchi. Nutraceutical supplement in the management of tendinopathies: a systematic review. Muscles Ligaments Tendons J. 2016 Jan-Mar; 6(1): 48–57. Published online 2016 May 19. doi:  [10.11138/mltj/2016.6.1.048] PMCID: PMC4915461. PMID: 27331031. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4915461/

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer is simply "we don't know". The burden of proof is on the manufacturer, who probably will never spend the millions to know. But since it is a nutritional agent, one does not have to substantiate claims, just print it up and sell em. But if you think eating collagen will help joints and tendons, you must also believe that eating teeth will help yours, and eating brain will make yours work better. And that dumping a can of gas on the engine under the hood will make your car more powerful. Unfortunately, collagen is digested into its components just like eating meat, calcium, proteins are digested. Don't waste your money. The claims have no basis in fact, nor do they make any biological sense.